# multiple done()s in a jquery deferred -- how does it work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

[Recently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14989628/1252748) I asked about how I could trigger a variable number of jquery `get()` requests and I received this code as a really efficient working solution:

```
var d = new $.Deferred();
var promise = d.promise();
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        promise = promise.then(function() {
            return $.ajax('/echo/json/', {
                data: {
                    json: JSON.stringify({foo: i})
                }
            }).done(function(data) {
                results[i] = data;
            });
        });
    }(i));
}

promise.done(function() {
    console.log(results);
});

d.resolve();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ym4c6/4/)

I'm looking for an explanation of how exactly this works with the multiple `done()`s attached to each `promise.then()`, and then the final `done()` attached to the promise itself. Is it that a promise (from what I understand is a special type of sort of deferred itself) can have a done, then the deferred itself can also have a done? If it weren't in a loop, what would this syntax look like for, say, three ajax requests in a row? Just trying to get my head around it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you have an array of deferred objects you can actually deal with them using `when` and `apply` to get the promises and then use `$.done()` on them:

```
$.when.apply($, deferredArray).done(function() {
   for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      //arguments[i] is the return of the singular done() statement    
   }
});
```

This works rather well when you don't know how many deferred objects you are working with.

Comment: I received an answer similar to this in the first post, but I really have no idea what is going on with `apply`. How is it being used? What's the `$` as the first parameter? Thank you

Comment: actually in the answer, they used `null` as the first parameter: `$.when.apply(null, dfdArr).done(function () {
        for (response in arguments) {
   html_str += arguments[response][0];`

Comment: and where does `arguments` come from? what generates that?

Comment: 1.  The apply() function is allowing us to pass every element in the deferredArray to the `when` of sorts.  2.  `arguments` is part of the baseline javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: The whole thing sort of reads in English "when all of the promises in the deferred array are done, do this..."

Answer (score 3):

A promise is a wrapper for the deferred that hides the `resolve` and `reject` methods, kind of the public interface of the deferred. For `then()` and `done()` it makes no difference if you use them on a deferred or on its promise. I'll use the term deferred for both from now.

That being said, `done()` returns the deferred itself which allows chaining. You can add as many done (and fail) handlers as you want like that. They will be called one by one.

`then()` returns a *new* deferred*, which can have its own done and fail handlers.

Note that in your code you replace the deferred in the `promise` variable on each loop iteration, so the final `done()` is not called on the original deferred but on the latest, returned by the last `then()`.

All calls chained in one line would look like that (each `then()` returns a new promise. I marked, on which the `done()` methods are called):

```
d.then().done().then().done().then().done().then().done().done();
         ^^^^^^        ^^^^^^        ^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        promise 1     promise 2     promise 3       promise 4
```

*) actually its promise

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I'm a bit confused by this: __"Note that in your code you replace the deferred in the promise variable on each loop iteration"__ `promise = promise.then` seems not so much like a replacement, but a concatenation. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Incorrect. I believe you code a lot of PHP? In JavaScript the dot is not a concatenation operator, it's like `->` in PHP ;-)

Comment: haha, yeah. Okay. Can you explain the last line that says "*) actually it's promise".

Comment: footnote explained: `then()` returns the promise of a new deferred object (**its**, not it's), not the deferred itself. But as I said, that makes no difference here.

Comment: "A promise is a wrapper for the deferred ...". Personally, I would find it confusing to have a Promise described as a "wrapper"; this doesn't conform to my mental model. For me, a better statement would be "a Promise is derived from a Deferred and exposes all of that Deferred's methods except those that resolve and reject". But if "wrapper" works for you (and anyone else), then I can't really say it's wrong.